# Installing OpenCv with gstreamer and ffmpeg support in Ubuntu 13.04 64bits

Tags: opencv, ubuntu, ffmpeg, gstreamer, ip-camera

I have tried to install OpenCV in Ubuntu 13.04 to use my IP-camera with no success. I made step by step as this tutorial http://www.ozbotz.org/opencv-installation/ but It does not work for me. I have tried with other tutorials too, but I have the same problem, the Opencv tries to connect the camera by hours without any response.
I'm using this code to capture the video:

cap=cv2.VideoCapture("http:/ /192.168.180.60:82/videostream.cgi?user=admin&pwd=")

And that link works in my browser, so, the streaming is alive. I have installed the Opencv in virtual machines 6 times trying different configurations without success, maybe I made a mistake in any step, but according to the tutorials I'm right, I'm trying with this:

```
sudo apt-get remove ffmpeg x264 libx264-dev
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install libgstreamer0.10-0 libgstreamer0.10-dev gstreamer0.10-tools gstreamer0.10-plugins-base libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev gstreamer0.10-plugins-good gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg 

sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0 libgtk2.0-dev libjpeg8 libjpeg8-dev yasm

cd ~
mkdir src
cd src/


git clone git://git.videolan.org/x264.git
cd x264/
./configure --enable-shared --enable-pic


sudo make install libfaac-dev libmp3lame-dev libopencore-amrnb-dev libopencore_amrwb-dev libtheora-dev libvorbis-dev libx264-dev libxvidcore-dev

cd ~/src
wget http://ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-0.11.1.tar.bz2
tar xvf ffmpeg-0.11.1.tar.bz2
cd ffmpeg-0.11.1

./configure --enable-gpl --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-nonfree --enable-postproc --enable-version3 --enable-x11grab --enable-shared --enable-pic

make
sudo make install


cd ~/src
wget http://www.linuxtv.org/downloads/v4l-utils/v4l-utils-0.9.5.tar.bz2

tar xvf v4l-utils-0.9.5.tar.bz2
cd v4l-utils-0.9.5
./configure  --enable-shared
make
sudo make install

sudo apt-get install libdc1394-22-dev
sudo apt-get install libvideo-ivtv-perl 


cd ~/src
wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/opencvlibrary/opencv-unix/2.4.2/OpenCV-2.4.2.tar.bz2
tar xvf OpenCV-2.4.2.tar.bz2
cd OpenCV-2.4.2/
mkdir build
cd build

cmake -D WITH_TBB=ON -D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -D WITH_V4L=ON -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON -D OPENCV_BUILD_3RDPARTY_LIBS=ON -D WITH_FFMPEG=ON -D WITH_GTK=ON -D WITH_OPENEXR=ON -D WITH_OPENNI=ON -D WITH_PNG=ON -D WITH_TBB=ON -D WITH_XINE=ON -D WITH_GSTREAMER=ON .
```